# ios app login session

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, session

I've look around and saw some of the ways are to use NSUserDefault, keychain and singleton on xcode to create a session for users who login through the app. I've also ask my friend and found it was possible to create a session and store it in the database.

I'm still new to programming and such, so please do not be offended by my silly question. What I want to know is, among the method mentioned above, which is the more appropriate method to hold a session. Is it a must that the session be held in the app? Is it possible to be the using webservice to create a session and store it in the db. Or can the session only be created by the app? (confuse about this)

I would like to know which is the most practical and of course, not that difficult for a beginner to implement and tweak. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You need a copy of the session token on your side so that the server can recognize you when you make a request. "Storing on web service" is not an option.

Comment: ahh sorry, I meant using webservice to create and store it in the db. Or can the session only be created by the app?

Comment: The web server creates a session, but the session token must be held by the client/app so that the server can relate.

Comment: sorry im lost about the web server part. Isnt a web server used to return a web page? but if im only using app, web service and db, in this context the web service is the webpage that im calling?

Comment: What I was explaining was how session works. Ultimately, the session token generated by the service/server must be held by someone to maintain the session (typically, the end-user's app/browser, and untypically, a man in the middle eavesdropping).

Comment: I see. Sorry for the misconception. Still a newbie at this. So would it be right to say that i can have my web service generate a token, and use a keychain from the app to hold the token?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any other way, but I think that is usually the way things are done.